# State not updating but values are there

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm using react native and expo with an image picker. For some reason, my choosefromlibrary function is not setting the state so I can read it and insert the file location for viewing. Location is not necessary, I tried setImageLocation(result.uri) to no avail so I was just trying different things.  result.uri prints with console.log, location prints with console.log, but when I console.log(imageSelected) nothing comes back

```
const [imageSelected, setImageSelected] = useState("");

const chooseFromLibrary = async () => {
    let location = "";

    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    location = result.uri;
    setImageSelected(location);
    console.log(imageSelected);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `imageSelected` state will not be reflected within your call to `chooseFromLibrary`. That value is fixed at whatever it was during the render where you called the function.

If you want to do something with the `location` that you set as your state, use `location` directly inside your function call (or you can use `useEffect` to do something every time `imageSelected` changes).